# How can you hide the fact your server has a WCF service located at MyService.svc

Tags: wcf

Is there a way to serve up a custom "Sorry not found" page from a direct access request to a WCF Service (.svc file) on a server running IIS 6.0, and .NET 3.5 SP1.

I have a requirement that my service in a Production environment is not discoverable. The requirement states that WSDL publishing should be off, and the request also states that when directly accessing the MyService.svc file via a HTTP Get Request that a "Sorry Not found" page is displayed instead.

I have no problem disabling the metadata in the config file.

`<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />`

But I can't figure out a way to not show the default .svc page.

**SERVICE**
This is a Windows© Communication Foundation service.

**Metadata publishing for this service is currently disabled.**

If you have access to the service, you can enable metadata publishing by completing the following steps to modify your web or application configuration file:
...

** Also posted at [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/78890/how-can-you-hide-the-fact-your-server-has-a-wcf-service-located-at-myservice-svc).

Comment: Have you tried turning off the httpGetEnabled? Doesn't do that exactly what you require?

Comment: Posted response at server fault (belongs on serverfault?). P.S. I won't blame you... serverfault is where questions go to die.

Comment: To clarify the httpGetEnabled is set to False for ServiceMetadata which is the WSDL definition.  But you'll still have the generic "This is a Service" page that is returned.

Comment: Also I posted here in Stackoverflow as ServerFault probably wouldn't know many details about web.config where the mostly likely answer if any resides.

Answer (score 1):

in web.config:

```
<httpHandlers>
    <remove verb="*" path="*.svc" />
    <add path="*.svc" verb="POST" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpHandler, System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" validate="false"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting http[s]HelpPageEnabled to false in Web.config. Example:

```
    <system.serviceModel>
      <behaviors>
         <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior>
               <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
               <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="false"/>
            </behavior>
         </serviceBehaviors>
      </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: As an added note, if using SSL also set the attributes `httpsGetEnabled` and `httsHelpPageEnabled`, respectively.